# Factors impacting propagation/gate delay

Tags: transistors

I was just wondering how the change in transistor sizing, load capacitance and supply voltage affected the propagation/gate delay of an inverter.

Comment: it depends on technology, if you talking about CMOS , yes RC is the effect. If it's TTL then it's dominated by recovery time of the junction. Could you be more specific or you asking generally?

Comment: It is for a CMOS inverter. Its a general question on the effects of increase or decrease in the transistor sizing, load capacitance and supply voltage on the gate delay on the inverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a particular output load, increasing the size of the gate will reduce the gate delay. However, it increases the input capacitance, and this increases the delay of the previous gate.

Increasing the supply voltage, without changing the *threshold* voltages of the gate, will reduce the delay at the cost of greater power consumption and heat dissipation. (This is why people overclocking their computers will often overvolt them as well).

Optimal gate sizing for a circuit is a painful problem. A technique called "logical effort" works quite well if you can custom size each gate and wire delay is small.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As a note: 
- I've generalized some of the operating equations for the sake of clarity and looking at the key parameters.
- this is for CMOS, which is the only way that gates are made these days.

Referring to the eqn's above the dominant/highest frequency obtainable is shown in eqn #2, where Gm is the transconductance of the transistors (roughly in units of inverse resistance => 1/ohms)  Cload is the capacitive load.

To get higher frequency you need to get higher Gm or dive a lighter load.

Eqn #1 shows that Gm is proportional to the Drain current.  Which makes sense, the higher the current you drive the faster you can charge a capacitor.

You get higher drive currents by varying the parameters in eqn #3.  Mu is the carrier mobility, Cox is the capacitance of the gate oxide, w= width of transistor, L= length of transistor and Vover is the over drive voltage of the transistor.

At a given process node, Cox is fixed for a given type of transistor.  SO the designer only really changes the W and the L.  In logic chips you really only change W as L should remain minimal length for yield reasons.

From #3 you can see that the wider the transistor the higher the Id, the faster the transistor is in charging the Cload.

Note that while Id follows V^2 that Gm only follows V linearly (eqn #1 has Id/Vover cancelling one of the Vover in V^2 term)

The Cload being driven is the Cox*W/L of the following gate.  So if you scale the one gate to drive harder, it looks like a heavier load to the gate that drives it.  But there are solutions to that as well.