# For gates of same drivestrength, what does gate delay depend on and how?

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, capacitance

I was wondering what the effect of input capacitance or fan-in is on gate delay.

Also, does anyone know of a relation that links gate delay with different circuit parameters (input load (fan-in), output load (fan-out), gate length/width, ..., ...) ?

**If I have gates of the *same drivestrength*, what exactly does gate delay depend on and how ?**

Comment: http://www.engr.uky.edu/~elias/lectures/ln_14.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43119/factors-impacting-propagation-gate-delay

Comment: Formally no - gate delay would be measured relative to a stated input condition, and things like fan-in or capacitance would merely make it harder for the test rig to achieve that test condition, rather than change the result of the test once it was properly conducted.  But in an application circuit, these could be practical issues.

Comment: More to the point, a gate can only respond to signals that arrive at its inputs. Any issues associated with getting those signal there are accounted for either as loading effects of the previous gate or as wiring delays.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but does anyone know the answer to my second question : If I have gates of the **same drivestrength**, what exactly does gate delay depend on **and how** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given two gates that are physically identical, the gate delay (as measured from 50% of input to 50% of output) can vary due to:

- Input rise/fall time and shape
- Input '0' and '1' levels
- Capacitive load on the output pin
- Resistive load on the output
- Output transmission line effects
- Local power supply voltage
- Local transistor temperature
- Radiation exposure (gamma, neutron, x-ray,...)
- Long-term electrical degradation effects
- Other stuff I haven't thought of

Answering "and how" is more difficult and is dependent on the particular transistor parameters and operating conditions, which are not specified.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the technology and voltage. A newer processes technology is faster than an older one. It also is generally at a lower voltage.